# Alias for function from DllImport

Tags: c#, powershell, dllimport

`[Win32]::ShowWindowAsync<<..>>` works, but this doesn't

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System;       // IntPtr
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;       // DllImport

public class Win32 {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr a, int b);
    
    public static bool f_1(IntPtr a, int b) {
        return (ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr a, int b));
    }
}
'@

write-host ([Win32]::f_1((Get-Process -Id $pid).MainWindowHandle, 2))

read-host 'end'
```

12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890

Comment: The method signature of `f_1` promises it'll return a `[bool]` value - but you never do! `return ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr a, int b);` from `f_1`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i did try `return (ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr a, int b));`, it doesn't work either .

Comment: Change `return (ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr a, int b));` to `return ShowWindowAsync(a, b);` (notice you don't need to "re-declare" the method parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with the C# code you pass off to `Add-Type`. Change the definition of the `f_1` method body so that it invokes the extern method correctly (remove the type declarations in front of the arguments you're passing) and make sure you `return` the return value from it to the caller:

```
public static bool f_1(IntPtr a, int b) {
    return ShowWindowAsync(a, b);
}
```